# Invalid read of size 4 error C programming

Tags: c, linux, makefile

For context: this is homework but it's for a small part of it.  I'm getting an error I can't figure out.

I'm using Valgrind in Linux and i'm getting an Invalid read of size 4 error.

```
424 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in file_path)
    by 0x4E3AE6C: create_deck
    by 0x400BBB: deal_one_card
    by 0x400D73: main

1 errors in context 1 of 1:
Invalid read of size 4:
  at 0x4E3AFFD: destroy_deck (in file_path)
  by 0x400C5A: deal_one_card (in file_path)
  by 0x400D73: main (in file_path)
Address 0x4 is not stack'd malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The Leak Summary:

```
still reachable: 424 bytes in 1 blocks
```

Here is the code for the two file paths:

Deck.c

```
char* suitNames[4] = {"hearts", "diamonds", "spades", "clubs"};
char* rankNames[13] = {"two", "three", "four", "five", "six",
   "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"};

int size_of_deck;

// create a standard 52-card deck
void* create_deck() {
   struct card **deck = malloc((sizeof(struct card*)) * NUM_OF_CARDS_IN_A_DECK + sizeof(struct card*));
   suit suits[NUM_OF_SUITS_IN_A_DECK] = { hearts, diamonds, spades, clubs };
   rank ranks[NUM_OF_RANK_IN_A_SUIT] = {ace, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten,
    jack, queen, king};
   int card_index;
   int suit_index;
   int i;
   card_index = 0;

   for (suit_index = 0; suit_index < NUM_OF_SUITS_IN_A_DECK; suit_index++) {
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_RANK_IN_A_SUIT; i++) {
        struct card *oneCard = malloc(sizeof(struct card));
        oneCard->card_suit = suits[suit_index];
        oneCard->card_rank = ranks[i];
        *(deck + card_index++) = oneCard;
    }
   }
   printf("current card index is: %d\n", card_index);
   *(deck + card_index) = NULL;
   size_of_deck = 52;
   return deck;
}

// free the deck memory
void destroy_deck(void* deck) {
   struct card **target_deck = deck;
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_CARDS_IN_A_DECK + 1; i++) {
    struct card *to_be_freed = *(target_deck+i);
    if (i < 52) {
        printf("Destroy Card: %s %s\n", suitNames[to_be_freed->card_suit],
        rankNames[to_be_freed->card_rank]);
    }
    free(*(target_deck+i));
   }
   free(target_deck);
}

// return a card, removing it from the deck
struct card* deal_card(void* deck) {
    struct card **current_deck = (struct card**) deck;
    // struct card *result = current_deck[0];
    struct card *result = current_deck[number_of_cards_remaining_in_deck(deck)-1];
    current_deck[number_of_cards_remaining_in_deck(deck)-1] = NULL;
    return result;
}


// return the number of cards indicated and remove them from the deck
struct card** deal_cards(void* deck, int num_cards) {
    struct card **current_deck = (struct card**) deck;
    struct card **result = (malloc(sizeof(struct card*) * num_cards)) ;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_cards; i++) {
        result[i] = deal_card(current_deck);
    }
    return result;
}


// Return the number of cards left in the deck
int number_of_cards_remaining_in_deck(void* deck) {
    struct card **target_deck = deck;
    int i = 0;
    while(*(target_deck + i) != NULL) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

and blackjack.c

```
int hand_value(struct card** hand, int num_cards) {
    int sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_cards; i++) {
    sum += getValue(hand[i]);
   }
   return sum;
}

// Compare two blackjack hands. Return a value < 0 if hand_one wins, a value of 0
// if the hands are equal and a value > 0 if hand_two wins
int blackjack_compare(struct card** hand_one, int num_cards_hand_one, struct card** hand_two, int num_cards_hand_two) {

   //  char* rankNames[13] = {"two", "three", "four", "five", "six",
   // "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"};
    int sum_1 = hand_value(hand_one, num_cards_hand_one);
    int sum_2 = hand_value(hand_two, num_cards_hand_two);

   if (sum_1 > sum_2) {
    return -1;
   } else if (sum_1 < sum_2) {
    return 1;
   } else {
    return 0;
   }
}

// Blackjack to_string, should return the value of the hand or "BUST" if the total
// is over 21
char* blackjack_to_string(struct card** my_hand, int num_cards_in_hand) {


    char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
    sprintf (buffer, "%d", hand_value(my_hand, num_cards_in_hand));
    char* bust = "BUST";
    return hand_value(my_hand, num_cards_in_hand) > 21
    ? bust
    : buffer;
}
```

We're using a Makefile for compiliation, and the code has been proven already to be working.  I know that the invalid read of size 4 error means that there's an integer somewhere in C memory land that needs to be freed and it isn't.

I cut out some code that I didn't think was relevant to make the code not as bulky.  If somethings missing please ask me about it.

I'd appreciate a fresh set of eyes to take a look and what I can't seem to find.  Anything would be very helpful.

Update:  Someone mentioned that the deal_one_card code wasn't mentioned.  It is located in the Main.c file.  Here it is:

```
void
deal_one_card() {
  // Create a deck
  void *deck = create_deck();

  // Deal a card
  struct card* one_card = deal_card(deck);
  printf("\tCard is the %d of %d\n", one_card->card_rank, one_card->card_suit);

  char* card_string;
  card_string = to_string(one_card);
  printf("\t%s\n", card_string);

  // free the string that was returned
  free(card_string);

  int cards_left = number_of_cards_remaining_in_deck(deck);
  printf("\tThere are %d cards left in the deck\n", cards_left);

  // free the card that we were dealt
  free(one_card);

  // Now destroy the deck
  destroy_deck(deck);
}
```

Comment: If you don't have luck here, CodeReview might be able to give you a hand.

Comment: The problem is in your `deal_one_card` function which you didn't show.

Comment: @user1717828: CodeReview doesn't allow asking about code with known problems.

Comment: "I know that the invalid read of size 4 error means that there's an integer somewhere in C memory land that needs to be freed and it isn't."  No, it actually means that you're reading an invalid memory location (dereferenced a wild pointed and tried to read the result).

Comment: The line `suit suits[NUM_OF_SUITS_IN_A_DECK] = { hearts, diamonds, spades, clubs };` uses several undeclared identifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that creates the deck puts a `NULL` at the end of the array of pointers. The `destroy_deck` function should be using that `NULL` to find the end of the list, and should **not** try to `free` that `NULL` pointer. So the `destroy_deck` function should look like this:

```
void destroy_deck(struct card **deck)
{
    for(int i=0; deck[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        printf("Destroy Card: %s %s\n", suitNames[deck[i]->card_suit], rankNames[deck[i]->card_rank]);
        free(deck[i]);
    }
    free(deck);
}
```

Comment: Didn't even realize that I was trying to free the NULL.

Thank you!

Comment: This is *a* problem, but not the one causing the crash.

Comment: Actually, `free(NULL)` is not a problem at all.  POSIX standard says "The `free()` function shall cause the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated; that is, made available for further allocation. **If ptr is a null pointer, no action shall occur.**"

Comment: @BenVoigt the C Standard also says that

Answer (score 2):

In `destroy_deck()`, you try to display the value of each card before you free its memory, using the following code:

```
if (i < 52) {
    printf("Destroy Card: %s %s\n", suitNames[to_be_freed->card_suit],
    rankNames[to_be_freed->card_rank]);
}
```

The problem is that your deck doesn't have 52 cards in it anymore, because you removed one in `deal_card()`.  When `i` is 51, the `to_be_freed` is `NULL` but `if (i < 52)` is true so you try to read the member variables, causing the crash.

The code @user3386109 gave you will fix the problem, but the crash was not from calling `free(NULL)` -- which is guaranteed to be harmless -- but from trying to print out the values of member variables.